# Laravel Lumen 7 API endpoint fails on date params

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

In Laravel Lumen 7, it seems to fail with params on a GET api endpoint, here's my endpoint:

```php
// API route group
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {

  // fetch data from external endpoint
  $router->get('local/stats/{from}/{to}', [
      'middleware' => 'auth',
      'uses' => 'ApiController@getLocalApiData'
  ]);

});
```

My URL is then: `/api/local/stats/2020-03-25T22:24:04.000+00:00/2020-03-26T10:24:04.000+00:00`

What doesn't it like about this?

Comment: Can you specify what excactly fails? Can you add a stacktrace to your question?

Comment: Do you url-encode the dates before actually calling the endpoint? Because those dates are not valid in an url as they are. `: / ? # [ ] @ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; =` are special characters in urls and must be encoded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: I'm getting a purple banner along the top of the page in PostMan with "Not Found", however, if I pass something like: `/api/local/stats/1/2` then it tells me the date isn't valid, but my endpoint is working, it just doesn't work with the dates, I'm using Carbon: `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $from)` and `$from` is coming into the function `getLocalApiData(Request $request, $from, $to)`